# different ways of declaring main function c#

Tags: c#

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
```

this is the most commonly used form to declare a Main function in C#. Is there any other way of declaring the Main function?

What will happen if we **interchange or miss out** some keywords?

Comment: cute puppies will die.. what happens when YOU try it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I think the better question is, What does each part of the typical Main method declaration mean?**

Can you take out some keywords? Sure, but the method will not necessarily be the same as the one defined below.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
```

**public** refers to the visibility, without public, the code will use its default visibility

**static** means that this is a class method. Without static, the method becomes an instance method.

**void** simply means that the return type is void. Can you change it to int? Sure, but you better return an int at the end.

**Main** is just the name. Names can obviously be switched but then you wouldn't call it the "main method" anymore

**string[] args** is just a parameter of arguments. Could you remove it? Yes, but then you could not use any arguments in the method.

***In General***: You can interchange things, but do not expect the exact same behavior out of the method. Understanding what each keyword does etc is the key here.

Answer (score 0):

if we interchange or miss out some keywords

it won't be the same `Main` function, it will just be a `overloaded` function, which cannot act as an `entry point` to your code.

and if you do not have atleast one `Main` function with the `correct syntax`, the compiler will complain.